# Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'. in django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to call a get api but it gives me this error everytime.

**The error:**

*AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `NestedSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance*.

**Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'.**

My models:

```
class Destination(models.Model):
    Continent_Name = (
        ('Europe', 'Europe',),
        ('Asia', 'Asia',),
        ('North America', 'North America',),
        ('South America', 'South America',),
        ('Africa', 'Africa',),
        ('Oceania', 'Oceania',),
        ('Polar', 'Polar',),
        ('Regions', 'Regions',),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=Continent_Name, default='Europe')
    top = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dest_image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name   
   
class Package(models.Model):
    TOUR_TYPE = (
        ('Custom-made trip with guide and/or driver', 'Custom-made trip with guide and/or driver',),
        ('Custom-made trip without guide and driver', 'Custom-made trip without guide and driver',),
        ('Group Tour', 'Group Tour',),
        ('Cruise Tour', 'Cruise Tour',),
    )

    operator = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Price in Nrs")
    price_2 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Price in $")
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    duration_hours = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name="Hours If One day Tour")
    discount = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Discount %", default=15)
    #discounted_price = models.IntegerField(default=230)
    #savings = models.IntegerField(default=230)
    tour_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TOUR_TYPE, default='Group Tour')
    new_activity = models.ManyToManyField(NewActivity)
    accommodation = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Guest House & Hotel')
    transport = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='Flight')
    age_range = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='6 to 79 years old')
    fix_departure = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, 1),
                                          (2, 2),
                                          (3, 3),
                                          (4, 4),
                                          (5, 5))
                                 )

    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, verbose_name="Thumbnail Image-Vertical")
    
    content =RichTextField()
    highlights = RichTextField()
    inclusions = RichTextField()
    exclusions = RichTextField()
    # itinerary = models.ManyToManyField(Itinerary)
    itinerary_text = RichTextField()
    faqs = RichTextField(blank=True)
    image_1= models.ImageField(blank=True,null = True,verbose_name="Image-Horizontal")
    image_2= models.ImageField(blank=True,null = True,verbose_name="Image-Square")
    image_3= models.ImageField(blank=True,null = True,verbose_name="Image-Sqaure")
    date_created = models.DateField()    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.package_name
```

My views:

```
class PackageSearchAPi(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Package.objects.all().order_by('package_name')
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        search = self.request.query_params.get('search',None)
        if search is not None:
            qs = Package.objects.filter(Q(destination__name__icontains=search)|
                                        Q(destination__continent__icontains=search)|
                                        Q(package_name__icontains=search)|
                                        Q(city__icontains=search)).disctinct()

        else:
            qs = Package.objects.values('id','destination','package_name','city')

        serializer = PackageSerializer(qs,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=200)
```

My serializers:

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ['id', 'operator','destination', 'package_name', 'duration', 'featured', 'price','price_2', 'discount',
                   'city', 'tour_type','new_activity', 'accommodation', 'transport', 'age_range',
                   'fix_departure', 'rating', 'image', 'date_created', ]

        depth = 1
```

Here I checked the code and nothing seems to be wrong in any part but keeps getting the same above error.

**Traceback:**

```
File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\apps\packages\views.py", line 251, in get
    return Response(serializer.data,status=200)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 760, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 260, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 677, in to_representation
    return [
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 678, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 529, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 516, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Saroj\Desktop\TravelCRM\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 487, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `NestedSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance.
Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

Comment: can you show the full traceback error? that would be much easier to find which lines showing the error

Comment: Try to change line `qs = Package.objects.values('id','destination','package_name','city')` to `qs = Package.objects.all()` first.

Comment: actually i need only those values in the response, thats why i had done it so.. using all wont solve my problem.

Comment: If you want only this values - you should change your serializer.Meta fields

Answer (score 0):

For nested relations you have to define nested serializer

```
class DestinationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    top = serializers.BooleanField()
    continent = serializers.CharField()

class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    destination = DestinationSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ['id', 'operator','destination', 'package_name', 'duration', 'featured', 'price','price_2', 'discount',
                   'city', 'tour_type','new_activity', 'accommodation', 'transport', 'age_range',
                   'fix_departure', 'rating', 'image', 'date_created', ]
```